# how to create an empty row in a tableview in javafx

Tags: javafx

I wonder if there is a way to add data to a tableview by double clicked on an empty row.
(In oracle tutorial about TableView, I can modified data by double clicked on it, I want to do the same thing with empty column).
If just I could know how to create an empty row, or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code adds a new Item to the table when a row is double-clicked. You basically have to set the RowFactory of the table.

```
 myTable.setRowFactory(new Callback<TableView<TableItem>, TableRow<TableItem>>() {

                @Override
                public TableRow<TableItem> call(TableView<TableItem> param) {
                    TableRow<TableItem> row = new TableRow<TableItem>();
                    row.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

                            @Override
                            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                                if ((event.getClickCount() == 2)) {
                                    //create a new Item and intialize it ...
                                    TableItem myItem = new TableItem();
                                    myTable.getItems().add(myItem);
                                } 
                            }

                        });

                    return row;
                }
            });
```

Comment: TableItem here is the Same thing of Person class ??

Answer (score 2):

In TableView the rows are creted from an items list, so for create empty row you simple use this code were Item() is the item of your items list.

```
tableView.getItems().add(new Item());
```